# Is it possible to give details rows in Kendo only after a certain number of rows?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I have been searching the internet for answer but I am not having any luck. I would like to know if it is possible to only show Kendo detail rows after 19 rows of data? I have a very odd requirement and I'm not sure it can be done. However if there is a solution out there, is there a small example I can see? Or a resource I have not found yet?

As a note a side note I am using Kendo with AngularJS.

Thank you in advance!

AnthonyFastcar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way to do this but I just hid the detail icon for the rows. I used the dataBound event.

```
dataSource: yourDataSouce,
dataBound: function(e) {
   var grid = this,
       grid2 = $('#yourGrid').data('kendoGrid');

   grid.tbody.find("tr[role='row']").each(function () {
      var index = $(this).index();
      if (index < 19) {
         $(this).find('.k-i-expand').removeClass('k-i-expand');
      }
   })
}
```

Additionally if you are trying to use a column, say an ID column you can do it like the below.

```
dataSource: yourDataSouce,
dataBound: function(e) {
   var grid = this,
   grid2 = $('#yourGrid').data('kendoGrid'),

   grid.tbody.find("tr[role='row']").each(function () {
      var data = grid.dataItem(this);
      if (data.yourColumnID < 19) {
         $(this).find('.k-i-expand').removeClass('k-i-expand');
      }
   })
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else who runs into the same issue.